# API.AI webhooks customization

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to use the option `Use webhook for slot-filling`, but am not finding a good example on the same.

Basically, am trying to provide options to user, context based. Ex: Lets say they want to order a pizza, the choices for crust could be Thin, Pan etc. so when the user starts saying 'Hi, I want to order a pizza', the reply will be 'Cool. Your options are Thin crust, Pan pizza'. Then depending on user choice, then it could give options for choices. I know how to do webhook coding part of it, but not clear on how to do API.AI configuration, since the webhook is for fulfilment, but I want that for the options to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API.ai documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/dialogs#non-linear-dialogs) for non-linear dialogs, the best way of doing it is by creating new intents for each possible choice and setting up contexts for it.

For example: 
You will have the root intent `Choose Pizza`, which will ask the user "Cool. Your options are Thin crust and Pan pizza." and set an output context **choose-pizza**.
[image]

Then, you will create the intents for each option: `ChoosePizza - thin crust`, and `ChoosePizza- pan pizza`, and set **choose-pizza** as input context.
[image]

And then go from there, using contexts and new intents.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This approach is good when you have limited set of option available which you can code in the API.ai itself. However when you have lots of options already available in your legacy database then you may want to use webhook to get the from your databases using API.

Comment: well the problem here is it passes all the parameters to the webhook on the 1st time, the 2nd time when you have a follow up intent that was triggered because an input context was set, all parameters are not being passed to the webhook, any ideas